# How do you perform a CROSS JOIN with LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, cross-join

How do you perform a CROSS JOIN with LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

A cross-join is simply the Cartesian product of two sets. There's no explicit join operator for it.

```
var combo = from p in people
            from c in cars
            select new
            {
                p.Name,
                c.Make,
                c.Model,
                c.Colour
            };
```

Comment: How do you write that `from p in people from c in cars` in lambda notation?

Comment: `people.SelectMany(p => cars, (p, c) => new { ... })`

Comment: For lambda syntax, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11395783/4294399.

Answer (score 43):

The same thing with the Linq extension method `SelectMany` (lambda syntax):

```
var names = new string[] { "Ana", "Raz", "John" };
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var newList=names.SelectMany(
    x => numbers,
    (y, z) => { return y + z + " test "; });
foreach (var item in newList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Based on Steve's answer, the simplest expression would be this:

```
var combo = from Person in people
            from Car    in cars
            select new {Person, Car};
```

Answer (score 13):

A `Tuple` is a good type for Cartesian product:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> CrossJoin<T1, T2>(IEnumerable<T1> sequence1, IEnumerable<T2> sequence2)
{
    return sequence1.SelectMany(t1 => sequence2.Select(t2 => Tuple.Create(t1, t2)));
}
```

Comment: Its type of argument and returns are `IEnumerable` not `IQueryable`, it works for Linq not Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 8):

Extension Method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> CrossJoin<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> sequence1, IEnumerable<T2> sequence2)
{
    return sequence1.SelectMany(t1 => sequence2.Select(t2 => Tuple.Create(t1, t2)));
}
```

And use like:

```
vals1.CrossJoin(vals2)
```

Comment: Its type of argument and returns are `IEnumerable` not `IQueryable`, it works for Linq not Linq to SQL.