# how to convert this sql using entity framework?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to convert the sql below

```
SELECT a.UserId, UserName, RealName, a.LocationID, LocationName, c.RoleId, RoleName
  FROM UserProfile a LEFT JOIN Location b ON a.LocationID = b.LocationID
                     LEFT JOIN webpages_UsersInRoles c ON a.UserId = c.UserId
                     LEFT JOIN webpages_Roles d ON c.RoleId = d.RoleId
```

to something like this:

```
db.UserProfile.join(...
```

I have tried to find how to do the join, but seems no luck. If there is anyone kind enough to tell me where I can find the example, I will be very grateful.

`webpages_UsersInRoles, webpages_Roles` is not in my data context and I don't intent to.

Thank you.

Comment: Pretty close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356439/left-join-in-linq-to-entities about LEFT JOIN with Entities but in your case Anders' answer is right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tables that you want to query must be in the *model*. If you are using model-first, it means you have to add them to the model. If you are using code first they will be in the model, if there are *navigation properties* from a class that is in the `DbContext`.

Once you have navigation properties in place, you should use them to access the related tables. Entity Framework will create the needed joins in the SQL automatically:

```
var q = from u in context.UserProfiles
  select new
  {
    u.UserId,
    u.Location.LocationName, // Using navigtion property instead of join
    // Add more properties here...
  };
```

Explicit joins should be avoided when using linq, [see more in this blogpost I wrote a few years back](http://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/asp-net-identity-and-owin-overview/).

Comment: Thank you. I move a bit further in my web application development journey :)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this using LINQ (please correct spell)

```
var data=(from d in obj.UserProfiles
           join d1 in obj.Locations on d.LocationID equals d1.LocationID 
          into sr from x in sr.defaultifEmpty()
           join d2 in obj.webpages_UsersInRoles on d.UserId  equals d2.UserId 
           into sr1 from x1 in sr1.defaultifempty() 
            join d3  in webpages_Roles on d.RoleId equals d3.RoleId
            into sr2 from x2 in sr2.defaultifempty()
             select new
                {
                   x2.RoleId,
                   d.UserId,

                 }   ).tolist();
```

For More refer [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356439/left-join-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: Thank you, Amol. Will try it immediately.