# Linq join tables using a flag column

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datatable, .net-3.5

I need join 3 tables using a column flag called `cashbillingtype_id`, this determines what table will joined.

For example i have this Datatable called [CashBillings]:

```
cashbilling_id  cashbillingtype_id
1               1
2               1
3               2
```

When:

```
cashbillingtype_id = 1 means: CashBillingsBills
cashbillingtype_id = 2 means: CashBillingsReturns
cashbillingtype_id = 3 means: CashBillingsCancellations
```

Now each table (`Bills`, `Returns`, `Cancellations`) have inside a column called `cashbillingBRC_total` i need to get this column data according the flag main datatable.

I Tryed:

```
(from CashBillings in _DataTable_Billings.AsEnumerable()
                                  join CashBillingsTypes in _DataTable_BillingsTypes.AsEnumerable()
                                      on CashBillings.Field<Int32>("cashbillingtype_id") equals CashBillingsTypes.Field<Int32>("cashbillingtype_id")
                                  select new
                 {
                     cashbilling_id = CashBillings.Field<Int32>("cashbilling_id"),
                     cashbillingBRC_total = (CashBillingsTypes.Field<Int32>("cashbillingtype_id") == 1 ?
                                                   (from CashBillingsBills in _DataTable_BillingsBills.AsEnumerable()
                                                    where CashBillingsBills.Field<Int32>("cashbilling_id") == CashBillings.Field<Int32>("cashbilling_id")
                                                    select CashBillingsBills.Field<Double>("cashbillingbill_total")).LastOrDefault()
                                                   :
                                                   (CashBillingsTypes.Field<Int32>("cashbillingtype_id") == 2 ?
                                                   (from CashBillingsReturns in _DataTable_BillingsReturns.AsEnumerable()
                                                    where CashBillingsReturns.Field<Int32>("cashbilling_id") == CashBillings.Field<Int32>("cashbilling_id")
                                                    where CashBillingsReturns.Field<Int32>("cashbillingreturnstatus_id") == 1 // Only Processed 
                                                    select CashBillingsReturns.Field<Double>("cashbillingreturn_total")).LastOrDefault()
                                                   :
                                                   (from CashBillingsCancellations in _DataTable_BillingsCancellations.AsEnumerable()
                                                    where CashBillingsCancellations.Field<Int32>("cashbilling_id") == CashBillings.Field<Int32>("cashbilling_id")
                                                    select CashBillingsCancellations.Field<Double>("cashbillingcancellation_total")).LastOrDefault())
                                                ),
                 }).Aggregate(DataTable_Billings, (dt, result) => { dt.Rows.Add(result.cashbilling_id, 
                                                                                result.cashbillingtype_id,
                                                                                result.cashbillingtype_name,
                                                                                result.cashbillingBRCstatus_id,
                                                                                result.cashbillingBRCstatus_name,
                                                                                result.cashbillingcustomer_fullname,
                                                                                result.cellar_name,
                                                                                result.cashbillingBRC_subtotal,
                                                                                result.cashbillingBRC_discount,
                                                                                result.cashbillingBRC_isv,
                                                                                result.cashbillingBRC_total,
                                                                                result.cashbillingBRC_date); return dt;
                 });
```

But this code is very very low efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with left joining all tables initially and just operating on fields in select statement?
In case you require information on left join, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19357132/2527768)