# how can i use ASP linq gridview to read different data name from two foreign keys in one table

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using ASP and SQL Server.

**Scenario:** One of my tables in the database twice a foreign key is a specific table used.

**The problem:** When I want to display different data entered on these foreign keys by linq in ASP GridView, it displays the same data for different values.

**Example:**
My first table that name "Table_1" with two data:

id2=Book,
id4=Student

[image]

and i have second table with name "foreignKeys" too that has data like this:

[image]

**Question:** how can i use linq gridview to read different data name (Book and Student) from "foreignKeys"?

My Html code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDeFrm" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="linq">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Book"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Student"></asp:BoundField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

My behind code:

```
 protected void linq_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Result = (from f in db.foreignkey
                    select new
                    {
                        f.userId,
                        f.Table_1.Name
                    }
                  ).ToList();
    }
```

Thank you for your attention earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have two from clauses instead of one. Give each one a different alias, and make sure each has a where clause that specifies what's joined to what.

At present, you just have a single from clause for the foreign key.

Take a look at the solution for this previous question: [c# Linq Join same table twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49070635/c-sharp-linq-join-same-table-twice)

It's similar enough that it should give you what you need.

Comment: Hello dude, can you more explain with programmatically codes?