# Set operation on a list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I got a list of strings,on which I would like to do an operation which concats each item with rest of the items. The below test fails at the moment, I think the join is not the correct linq method I should be using- can you please let me know how to get this done? The pattern of the output should tell how the projection should be,if not the rule is simple:take one item and concatenate with all the other items and then move to the next item.Test below:

```
[Test]
        public void Should_concatenate_all_items()
        {
            var items = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c", "d"};

            var concatenatedList = items .Join(items , x => x, y => y, (x, y) => string.Concat(x, y));

            foreach (var item in concatenatedList)
            {                
                //Should output:ab
                //Should output:ac
                //Should output:ad
                //Should output:bc
                //Should output:bd
                //Should output:cd
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
```

*Note*: I'm using .NET 3.5.

Comment: What is `potentialItems` and it's elements? Is that the full output or a sample?

Comment: Okay, thats what I thought

Comment: Why use Linq for something like this? It's just a nested loop, it would be done already, and in a couple of months time, what it was doing would be extremely obvious. Idea behind Linq was greater power of expression, not express everything in it no matter what...

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this:

```
var concatenatedList =
    from x in items.Select((str, idx) => new { str, idx })
    from y in items.Skip(x.idx + 1)
    select x.str + y;
```

Or in fluent syntax:

```
var concatenatedList =
    items.Select((str, idx) => new { str, idx })
         .SelectMany(x => items.Skip(x.idx + 1), (x, y) => x.str + y);
```

Comment: +1. Following question have more samples of [cross join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547/how-do-you-perform-a-cross-join-with-linq-to-sql) used here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var concatenatedList = (from i in items
                     from x in items
                     where i != x
                     select string.Concat(i, x)).ToList();
```

For the exact output that you listed:

```
 var concatenatedList = (from i in items
                     from x in items
                     where i != x && items.IndexOf(i) < items.IndexOf(x)
                     select string.Concat(i, x)).ToList();
```

Comment: I gave another one, that wasn't clear when I wrote the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I think my solution may be overkill, but in real world situations it is probably more helpful. Also, I could not find a clean way to do it in Linq. Linq's Except does not seem suited for this.

You can use an IEnumerator to enumerate the values for you.

```
public class ConcatEnum : IEnumerator
{
    public List<String> _values;

    // Enumerators are positioned before the first element 
    // until the first MoveNext() call. 
    int position1 = 0;
    int position2 = 0;

    public ConcatEnum(List<String> list)
    {
        _values = list;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        position2 = Math.Max(position2 + 1, position1 + 1);
        if (position2 > _values.Count - 1){
            position1++;
            position2 = position1 + 1;
        }

        return position1 < _values.Count - 1;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        position1 = 0;
        position2 = 0;
    }

    object IEnumerator.Current
    {
        get
        {
            return Current;
        }
    }

    public String Current
    {
        get
        {
            try
            {
                return _values[position1] + _values[position2];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        this.Reset();
        while (this.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
var items = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
foreach (var i in new ConcatEnum(items))
{
    //use values here
}
```