# linq join tables with multiple columns with or condition

Tags: linq

I want to join 3 tables. From which two tables join with multiple columns by "or" condition then join 3rd table to the result of first two.

example as below:

```
    from t1 in db.table1
    from t2 in db.table2 
    where (t1.ISIN == t2.ISIN_GrowthDiv || t1.ISIN==t2.ISIN_DivReinv)  
    join t3 in table3 on t2.SchemeID equals t3.SchemeId
```

now tell me above query is correct or not?

Comment: do you have data to test it?

Comment: Yes ,  I have checked the query in SQl profiler third table is crossjoin with above result query which I don't want. I want inner join

Comment: can you post your data (or a part of it) to let us check what happens?

Comment: No I cannot Sorry

Comment: Are you sure you don't have duplicated data? Your code seems working...

Comment: No I don't have duplicated data.Basically my  Problem is third table is join as crossjoin to the result of first two tables & I Want innerjoin

Comment: Also, what is your select clause?

Comment: Anyway try the last query in the edit section of my answer, that should take care of your problem.

Comment: When I do this with LINQ to SQL for MS SQL Server, I get `CROSS JOIN` for the first two tables and `INNER JOIN` on the last table - what database engine/provider are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show your `select` clause, I will do a sample `select`; of course replace it with your own.

I have also created sample data, as you said you can't share yours, and stored in `table1`, `table2` and `table3`:

```
var table1 = new List<Table1>()
{
    new Table1() { ISIN = 1 },
    new Table1() { ISIN = 4 }
};

var table2 = new List<Table2>() {
    new Table2() { ISIN_DivReinv = 0, ISIN_GrowthDiv = 1, SchemeID = 111 },
    new Table2() { ISIN_DivReinv = 1, ISIN_GrowthDiv = 0, SchemeID = 111 },
    new Table2() { ISIN_DivReinv = 1, ISIN_GrowthDiv = 0, SchemeID = 222 },
    new Table2() { ISIN_DivReinv = 2, ISIN_GrowthDiv = 2, SchemeID = 111 }
};

var table3 = new List<Table3>()
{
    new Table3() { SchemeId = 111 },
    new Table3() { SchemeId = 333 }
};

var Result =
    from t1 in table1
    from t2 in table2
    where (t1.ISIN == t2.ISIN_GrowthDiv || t1.ISIN == t2.ISIN_DivReinv)
    join t3 in table3 on t2.SchemeID equals t3.SchemeId
    select new { t1.ISIN, t2.ISIN_DivReinv, t3.SchemeId };
```

These are the results I'm getting:

[image]

As you can see, there's no cross-join; which is not surprising, since by default LINQ provides inner joins with the `join` operator and the only way to get cross joins is to just select without join, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/679174/5480409) answer.

---

**EDIT: WHAT IF T3.SCHEMEID HAS DUPLICATES?**

A "special" case is when `t3` contains duplicated values, e.g. like

```
var table3 = new List<Table3>()
{
    new Table3() { SchemeId = 111 },
    new Table3() { SchemeId = 111 }
};
```

In this case you will get 4 rows instead of 2, since the inner join will properly occur for the two rows of `t2` twice, one per matching value of `t3`.

[image]

This doesn't make it a "cross-join" anyway, but you can  take distinct values of t3.SchemeId if your select doesn't need values from `t3`:

```
var Result =
    from t1 in table1
    from t2 in table2
    from t3 in table3.Select(f => f.SchemeId).Distinct()
    where (t1.ISIN == t2.ISIN_GrowthDiv || t1.ISIN == t2.ISIN_DivReinv) & t3 == t2.SchemeID
    select new { t1.ISIN, t2.ISIN_DivReinv, t2.SchemeID };
```

[image]

Comment: Let me check this example in my pc

Comment: Yes Your Example works Fine, but when I tried it with my tables ......it again shows cross join in sql profiler.  So I have changed my code & now I am fetching data using stored procedure

Comment: did you check "EDIT: WHAT IF T3.SCHEMEID HAS DUPLICATES?"?

Comment: I think that `from t3 in table3.Select(f => f.SchemeId).Distinct()` might be the crucial part

Comment: k let me try this also