# cross join LINQ query convert to lambda with navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this LINQ query:

```
from device in _context.Device
from data in _context.Data.OrderByDescending(_ => _.Time).Take(1)
select data;
```

I use it with .NET5 EF, and I have navigation properties.

Device looks like this:

```
Device 
------------ 
DeviceId int (Primary key)
DeviceInformation varchar(max)  
...
```

Data looks like this:

```
Data  
------------ 
DataId int (Primary key)  
DeviceId int (Foreign key for Device)  
Time datetime
...
```

How can I convert it as a lambda query?

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/56547/861716, etc.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. If you really have a relevantly different solution that the duplicate please contact @GertArnold and convince them that this is not a duplicate. Or write reasons into comment here or edit the question to highlight the difference. Then, when the question is reopened, add an answer.